# Transfer file to TeamCity agents

Tags: teamcity, build-automation

I have a CI/CD pipeline in TeamCity and I'm trying to make a change to it where I push the build artifacts to a repository.

Now this repo requires a certain certificate to be passed along the push request. For that I need the certificate file to exist on each TeamCity agent.

How do I setup TeamCity to have this file transferred to agents before a build is triggered?

Comment: Is adding the certificate to version control an option? This would ensure it's downloaded to the agent's working directory during the build.

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd it is an option, but logically this certificate isn't part of the project itself, it's part of its deployment settings that should go into TeamCity.

Comment: You could have a separate build config with a separate VCS to a separate repo containing the certificate - This could then be an artifact dependency that you can reference in the deployment configurations that need it.